# Should all "Hidden features of XXX" questions be closed and locked?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

A lot of these are on the close votes list in the 10K tools today.  What is the policy on these **now**.  I know in the past they were allowed, but new question like them **now** get closed very quickly.

Answer (score 16):

(note, this is a moderator *opinion*, not *moderator policy*.)

I am closing and locking these when they are flagged.

In general they are used for two reasons:

1. People still want to leave answers on these from time to time, but most importantly,
2. People use these as justification to post new similar questions and demand they (the new questions) are kept. Some of these end up in a close/reopen war where two camps of people fight over the right to have the last say in this. That's why I also lock these when I close them.

If we close and lock them, they are still here, but it is more clear that they are not really welcome. I still think many of these contain some useful information, so flags to delete them have been denied for now.

Comment: Adding a standard note to the top of the question, saying they are being kept for historical reasons etc may be good as well.

Comment: That, I agree with, wish I thought about that sooner, but thanks for reminding me, I'll go back to the questions I can find and do that.

Comment: Is it necessary to close *and* lock them? Couldn't they just be locked?

Comment: Closing the question also lists the reason for why they are no longer constructive. Just locking it doesn't tell you why. I'd be happy to revert those posts I closed today, but first I want to know why you want them just locked, and not closed as well?

Comment: What about one of the mods doing a search for "Hidden features of " in question titles and hitting them all in one go"?

Answer (score 4):

There's definitely some good information in some of those.  SO still needs a standard way of handling those kind of questions.  They really shouldn't be closed, unless they're duplicating a pre-existing one, though in that case they should be merged.